# JEditorPane HTMLDocument adds p-implied into HTML unnecessarily when setCharacterAttributes called

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane, dom, htmleditorkit

I am creating an editor using  `JEditorPane`, `HTMLDocument` and `HTMLEditorKit`. I have a toolbar which has various components to change style attributes of the editor. One of them is a `JComboBox` to change the `ZOOM_FACTOR` attribute. The code below is the code that executes when that `JComboBox` 's value changes.

```
    final SimpleAttributeSet attrs = new SimpleAttributeSet();
    zoomCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String s = (String) zoomCombo.getSelectedItem();
            s = s.substring(1, s.length());
            double scale = new Double(s).doubleValue() / 100;
            editorPane.getDocument().putProperty("ZOOM_FACTOR", new Double(scale));

            try {
                StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) editorPane.getDocument();
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, 1, attrs, true);
                doc.insertString(0, "", null); // refresh
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error("Hata", ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

`doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, 1, attrs, true);` is the line where root of my problem starts. After this line of code executes, `<p-implied>` is added into the `<head></head>` part of the `HTML text` in the `JEditorPane.getText`. And after this happens, if some certain pattern of events occur my `HTML text` gets corrupted. Is there any way how not to create `<p-implied>` along? If not so what could be the best workaround for this problem?

PS : There is something old reported [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4625179?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel) in the JDK Bug System. It is reported for a different reason, but it is shown there also, that the same `<p-implied>` is being added into `<head></head>` afterwards. I know the problem reported in this link uses `JTextPane` (a subclass of `JEditorPane`) and `setCharacterAttributes` method in the `JTextPane` class but that method also calls same `setCharacterAttributes` method I used inside itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use 0 position, but for HTMLDocument the positions belong to HEAD (not BODY) section.

Looks like you use it just to refresh the content. You can apply the same code for the end of the document.

```
doc.setCharacterAttributes(doc.getLength(), 1, attrs, true);
```

Thus the attribute change event is applied to the BODY.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked with additional small change, I changed the line after this line to refresh the component. Is there any source to gain better understanding of HtmlDocument and JEditorPane. Documentation is not even close to enough.

Comment: I've implemented the tool http://java-sl.com/JEditorPaneStructureTool.html to investigate Document structure and views structure

Comment: Thank you @StanislavL, your tool helped investigate an issue I had with `JTextPane`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55265610/1083697