# How to remove border around image inside link tag in Swing's JTextPane?

Tags: swing

When using following HTML code inside `JTextPane`:

```
Just an image: <img src="image.png" /><br/>
<a href="https://example.net">A link</a><br/>Image inside link:
<a href="https://example.net"><img src="image.png"></a>
```

You'll get the following result:

[image: Border around image demo]

I've added a single CSS rule to make the link color red:

```
StyleSheet css = htmlEditorKit.getStyleSheet();
css.addRule("a { color: red; }");
```

As you can see on the screenshot, this turned the image frame red as well, from which I conclude that it is the `<a>` tag that is causing the border to appear.

---

How to get rid of this border around image inside `<a>` tag?

I've tried overriding border with another rule, but it did not work:

```
css.addRule("img { border: 0; }");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at code of `HTMLEditorKit`, you can see that `<img>` tag is rendered using class `ImageView`, which contains following code:

```
    borderSize = (short)getIntAttr(HTML.Attribute.BORDER, isLink() ?
                                   DEFAULT_BORDER : 0);
```

and `DEFAULT_BORDER` is hardcoded to `2`.

Note, that it checks an *HTML* attribute. If HTML attribute `border` is not specified, then the border of images is `2` when inside a link, and zero otherwise.

A solution would be to specify `border` directly inside the `<img>` tag:

```
Image inside link:
<a href="https://example.net"><img src="image.png" border="0"></a>
```

[image]